# how to insert json image data in to uitableview ios(obj -C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

hear is the response and please do explain in detail 
Thanks in advance

```
{
  "success": "true",
  "data": {
    "per_page": 25,
    "total_records": "12",
    "products": [
      {
        "product_id": "48",
        "price": "1699.0000",
        "image": "data/newimages/1.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "description": "nill",
        "name": "Buy 2 Denim Jeans &amp; 1 Round Tee &amp; 1 Casual Shirt get one  Casual Watch free"
      },
      {
        "product_id": "47",
        "price": "2500.0000",
        "image": "data/newimages/2.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "description": "nill",
        "name": "2 Branded denim Jeans &amp; 2 Casual Shirt + 1 round neck tee and get a Watch , Card Holder free"
      },
      {
        "product_id": "43",
        "price": "1999.0000",
        "image": "data/newimages/12.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "description": "nill",
        "name": "Complete Formal Combo By 2 cotton formal trousers &amp; 2 Formal Shirts + 1 formal shoe &amp; 2 formal Belts"
      },
      {
        "product_id": "40",
        "price": "1599.0000",
        "image": "data/newimages/8.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "description": "nill",
        "name": "7 printed super hero &amp; disney Round Neck Tees get 1 Sneaker Shoes free"
      },
      {
        "product_id": "39",
        "price": "2000.0000",
        "image": "data/newimages/18.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "description": "nill"
        "name": "Its time to steel the looks with these 5 100% cotton formal Shirts"
      }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by downloading SDWebImage library, after downloading sdwebimage you need to first import it

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

After import check my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method of UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[cell.ImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“URL String”] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“Place holder image name“]];
return cell;}
```

You can get the array using the below code

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryYouAlreadyHave;
NSArray *productArray = [[[dictionaryYouAlreadyHave objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"products"]];
```

And you can get image name using below code

```
NSDictionary *dict = [productArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imgName = [dict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

Comment: Please tell me how do i take the all images in to array  i tried following but the app is crashing            NSLog(@"imageurl====>: %@ ",[[[json objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"products"]objectForKey:@"image"]);

Comment: You are having Dictionary > Array > Dictionary,

Comment: You need to get array from the key products, let me show you the code

Comment: NSDictionary *dictionaryYouAlreadyHave;
        NSArray *productArray = [[[dictionaryYouAlreadyHave objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"products"]objectForKey:@"image"];

Comment: Thank you so much got it

Comment: Is this is the right way to insert the image urls in the table view     imgNamestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.insoldeals.com/image/%@",[dict objectForKey:@"image"]];
                    
                NSLog(@"Res:====>IMAGE_URLS %@",imgNamestr);           following way i try to insert the array of images in table view but showing null values      [cell.pro_image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgNamestr]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    NSLog(@"table insert images%@",imgNamestr);

Comment: [cell.ImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“URL String”] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“Place holder image name“]];

Comment: add complete url, imgNamestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http//www.insoldeals.com/image/%@",[dict objectForKey:@"image"]];